# Not giving expected output

Tags: shell

Program is not working as expected. Could any one help for this issue?

Input for shell file i.e. `i -> abc.xml`

Expected output is : `grep abc $/nav/lab/xyz.lst`

File name : sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the test name:"
read i
echo $i | set new_val = "`$cut -d '.' -f 1`"
echo $new_val
grep "`echo $a`" $/nav/lab/xyz.lst
```

Comment: read i
a="`echo $i | cut -d '.' -f 1`"
echo "grep $a /home/cg/root/nav.txt"

Comment: Is your expected output a shell command?

Answer (score 0):

**Change these lines:**

> echo $i | set new_val = "`$cut -d '.' -f 1`"
>
> grep "`echo $new_val`" $/nav/lab/xyz.lst

**to this:**

```
new_val=$(echo $i | cut -d '.' -f 1)
grep $new_val "/nav/lab/xyz.lst"
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Enter the test name:
>
> abc.xml
>
> abc
>
> grep abc $/nav/lab/xyz.lst

Comment: Actually, I want to grep abc strings form the $/nav/lab/xyz.lst file

Comment: `$/nav/lab/xyz.lst` $ symbol is not a valid in a file path. Updated answer.

Comment: sorry frd but it is not working...:(

following error shows after executing shell file

Error :

nav.sh: line 3: new_val: command not found

Comment: There should be no spaces before or after `=`. Check it.